# How do I inject a dependency into an extension method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, extension-methods

I am currently working with an ASP.NET MVC 4 project, using C#.

I would like to create an extension method that accepts various types of methods, wraps those methods in a `try/catch`, and then returns the results of the method call if the call succeeds.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public static object HandleServerError(this object obj)
        {
            object result = null;
            try
            {
                result = obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandlers.ThrowServerErrorException(ex);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Here is an example of the extension method in use:

```
var test = webClient.DownloadString(uri).HandleServerError().ToString();
```

This works ok, but the `webClient.DownloadString(uri)` part is executed and then passed into `HandleServerError` as a string which is NOT what I want.

What I am wanting to do is INJECT `webClient.DownloadString(uri)` into the extension method so that the actual method call is wrapped into a try/catch.

### Please note

I realize that there are arguments against try/catch statements, but not looking to start a debate over the subject--the core of this question is centered on the dependency injection problem.  Thanks for all answers though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an extension method for a callback (a `Func<T>`), not an object.

Something like this:

```
static class FuncExtensions  {
    public static T HandleServerError<T>(this Func<T> func) {
        T result = default(T);
        try {
            result = func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Handle exception here.
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And in use it would look something like this:

```
new Func<string>(() => webClient.DownloadString(uri)).HandleServerError();
```

But this whole thing would probably be better implemented with a regular method call than extension methods.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt As all of us have said, this really shouldn't be an extension method as the syntax for it isn't as nice.  You should just use a regular static method.

Comment: @Servy--Thanks.  I see your point, but upon trying to call as a regular method the way you suggested I encountered compilation errors.  I can't remember what they were at this point, but the syntax in the call example was off a little.  I really appreciate your help, however, and anyone else reading this should consider your answer as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, can the person that voted ken's answer down please comment?  The answer is correct and most directly answered the question.

Comment: +1 for "this whole thing would probably be better implemented with a regular method"

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is pass in a delegate.  `Func` would make sense here:

```
public static T HandleServerError<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    T result = default(T);
    try
    {
        result = func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandlers.ThrowServerErrorException(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

you could then call it like:

```
int test = HandleServerError(() => 0);
```

or

```
string test = HandleServerError(webClient.DownloadString(uri));
```

(You could still keep it an extension method, but I think it would make more sense and be easier to use as a non-extension method.)

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of is this:

```
public static T HandleServerError<T>(this Func<T> action) 
{ 
    T result = default(T);
    try
    {
        result = (T)action();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandlers.ThrowServerErrorException(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
var test = new () => { return WebClient.DownloadString(uri); }.HandleServerError().ToString();
```

The only issue is you may end up with a lot of these so that you can handle all of the different types of needs, but maybe not a big deal.